# The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just downloaded the latest WAMP (v 2.1) and basically did a fresh install.

I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and I get this error:

> Error MySQL said:
>
> ## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

What the heck? What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the MySQL listener up and running on port 3306?  I'd try logging in with the command line client to see.  You should also see if mysqld.exe is running.  If not, start it up.  Figure out how to make it run as a service.

Comment: Also check for any firewall rules that might be blocking the port.

Comment: The mysql console asks for a password. I don't know it? Also when click on WAMP and go to MySQL menu.. then go to Services .. I can only click "Start/Resume service" so.. it's not even on?

Comment: You should have set up an admin username and password when you installed, then created a credential for each database you create.  If the service isn't started, do tell it to resume.  You can also try starting it on the command line.  If there's an exception message you'll get to read it.

Comment: I press "Start/resume service" and nothing happens... and command line? I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a firewall blocking mysql port

Answer (score 0):

php.ini - under your php/bin folder

```
mysql.default_socket = "C:/www/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

my.ini - under you mysql folder

```
socket      = "C:/www/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

This worked for me. Using WAMP2.2 with Windows XP.

I also made sure port was set to 3306 in both.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across with a solution after a 10 hours brain storming.
Please follow the below steps:

1- Go to my.ini  file located in your Web server directory and changed the setting for mysql socket = "MySQL" to `"/tmp/mysql.sock"`.

2- Do the same in the php ini file and restart your Web Server!

Hope above steps are useful to get the solution.
if it is enough to solve the problem, Please mark the answer resolved .